# determining if notification panel is visible

Tags: android

I'm implementing youtube style status bar behaviour in my app.
The status bar is normally hidden, when user press a button the status bar appear, and then disappear after 2 seconds:

```
public void displayStatusBarTimed(){

    // Show status bar
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

The problem I have, comes up when the notification panel is expanded (the drop down panel from the status bar), it is cleared after 2 seconds together with the status bar.
How can I prevent this?
I did some tests and found that onPause is not called when the panel is visible.
I haven't found a way to check if the panel is visible.
I'd like to start the 2 seconds timer after the panel is closed...
any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [samples for immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#nonsticky), you should override `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)`:

```
private final Handler mDecorHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   if (!hasFocus) {
       // Remove any pending messages/runnables
       mDecorHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
   } else {
       mDecorHandler.post(...)
   }
}
```